# updates not updating due to installation of untrusted packages in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, package-management

[image]I ve had an issue with the update center about a month and a half ago and somehow resolved it.Today I checked my updates,clicked install and recieved an error message of "reguires installation of untrusted packages".The only thing I can think of that I ve done was installing playonlinux and wine.Anyone having or had this issue?

Comment: Did you installed WINE by adding  PPA. Or any other package through 3rd party PPA.

Comment: no I didnt.I installed playonlinux from software center and it installed wine

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal and post the output.

Comment: I ran -get update.everything went through fine it updated lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will try and update the sources packages to check for available updates that can be updated in your system.

`Untrusted packages` errors mostly arise due to missing keys , if that is the case then note the missing keys combination of Numbers and Letters and do

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com XXXXXXXXX
```

Where `XXXXXXXXX` is the key from the error you get.

Another reason would be the Mirrors not properly synced , running the Update command mostly solves them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I just had this issue myself. I checked my sources in /etc/apt/ and the only things I have that are non ubuntu.com addresses are launchpad.com for Cinnamon and opera.com for the  Opera browser. I finally did an 'apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded' in terminal (the old fashioned way!) and had no problem.

Just a little editorial comment - from the wacky new nameserver system to this little glitch, Ubuntu isn't really showing the quality it did in the past, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem here: [ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-gpg-error-badsig.html](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-gpg-error-badsig.html)

```
sudo apt-get update
```

gave me errors with `BADSIG XXXXXX`

The linked fix appears to replace the updaters keylist.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. A link only answer is not considered to be appropriate. Websites close, links break. Please provide the essential steps for the solution by editing the answer and use the link as reference. See the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).